# How to subclass QRunnable to run any member function?

Tags: c++, qt

Given a certain delay I would like to run a member function from a class X by supplying a QRunnable to the QThreadPool global instance. The QRunnable subclass' constructor will take a delay int, the instance pointer, the member function pointer and the function arguments.

I was wondering how I should proceed. I have the following code and i'm kind of stuck on how to solve this issue.

```cpp
template<typename I, typename F, typename ...Args>
class Task : public QRunnable{

public:
    Task(int delay, I &&instance_ptr, F &&func_ptr, Args &&... args):
        delay(delay),
        instance_ptr(std::forward<I>(instance_ptr)),
        func_ptf(std::forward<F>(func_ptr)),
        args_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    void run() override
    {
        QThread::sleep(delay);

        (instance_ptr->*func_ptr)(args_tuple) // This is where i don't know how to unpack the tuple
    }
private:
    int delay;
    I instance_ptr;
    F func_ptr;
    std::tuple<Args...> args_tuple;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have C++17, you can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply).

If you are using a previous version of C++, you have to make your own trick to unpack the tuple. There are plenty of them on the Internet if you search on how to call function with tuples.

The [documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) of `std::apply`, also gives you a possible implementation:

```
namespace detail {
template <class F, class Tuple, std::size_t... I>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply_impl(F&& f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
}  // namespace detail

template <class F, class Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Tuple&& t)
{
    return detail::apply_impl(
        std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Tuple>(t),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>{});
}
```

Comment: std::apply works perfetly for this case ! Thanks.
On anoter note creating a Task pointer gets me a class template argument deduction failed error is this expected behavior ?